# HTML/CSS not working in <= IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following layout, which works fine in the latest Chrome, and also in IE8, and IE9.  For some reason it's not working properly in anything less than IE8:

http://oshirowanen.x10.mx/

For some reason the footer is bigger in IE versions below IE8.  Why might this be?

Comment: Someone else might, but I'm not going to dig through your code. Please post the *relevant* (but not *all*) markup and css in the question.

Comment: There are a lot of differences between how IE < 9 and every other browser out there render CSS. Without any of your code or any specific questions, you're basically just asking us to go through your entire page and pick out problems. Please be more specific by listing specific problems and code to go along with them, preferably specific code foreach problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `clear: both;` from #footer and add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` before `<div id="footer">`

it's just IE magic.